# Why are PATH args to subprocess.run() not portable between Linux and MacOS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, macos, subprocess

I'm having difficulty with portability between Linux and MacOS with the `subprocess.run()` method.

On Linux, a command like below works just fine as long as `someCommand` is in my `PATH` (set in `~/.bashrc`).

```py
subprocess.run(["someCommand", "foo", "bar"])
```

However, on MacOS, the same command does not run, even though `someCommand` is in my `PATH`. Instead, I get an error like:

```sh
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'someCommand'
```

There are many other answers on StackExchange which say "just use `shell=True` and convert the args list to a string", which seems like a fine solution for me, but I am curious why Python on MacOS doesn't seem to inherit `PATH` from the environment, while it clearly does on Linux. Can anyone clarify this for me, and/or point me to some relevant docs?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. In your script, before that `subprocess.run(...)` line, what does `import os; print(os.environ.get("PATH"))` show? Is the path you expect there?

Comment: Programs like the python interpreter inherit their environment (including `PATH`) from whatever parent process forked them, so the `PATH` your program gets will depend on exactly how python was started. Exactly how are you running your script?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for your time! `print(os.environ.get("PATH"))` shows the correct `PATH` string with all my customizations from `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks for your time! That's interesting, especially considering that `print(os.environ.get("PATH"))` shows the correct path per @juanpa.arrivillaga's comment. I am launching it from the MacOS terminal app (running Bash 5 via Homebrew) with command `python3 myScript.py`.

Comment: (Just brainstorming) Could it be that someCommand on the Mac is not an executable, but an alias, a shell function, or something other that does not exist in the file system?

Comment: Does it work when you use `shell=True`?

Comment: @TurePålsson They're executables in my `PATH` (it happens with any of them I've added to `.bash_profile`), and they're aliases or symlinks. Thanks for your brainstorming, I appreciate everyone in this thread for letting me know I have some kind of config problem rather than something inherent in Python!

Comment: @JanWilamowski Yes, if I convert the args list to a string and pass `shell=True`, it works as expected!

Comment: Sounds like it has something to do with the shell configuration, e.g. the command is an alias like Ture Pålsson suggested. If it was a symlink, the command should still be found but that's not the case for shell aliases.

Comment: Wild guess: does the relevant entry in `PATH` start with a literal `~`? If so, bash will resolve that to your home directory, but nothing else will. If so, change how you add that path entry so it expands to the actual path to your home directory. See [this question on Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/434805/zsh-does-not-find-script-in-path-while-bash-does-echo-path-is-the-same).

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks, I hadn't considered this! I have `~` in my `PATH` on my Linux machine and it seems Python has no problem finding those executables. Anyway, I just figured it out. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem on my Mac was that all the executables in my `PATH` were declared in `~/.bash_profile` instead of `~/.bashrc`.

I never knew this before today, but `.bash_profile` is only sourced on login shells, so I guess Python spawns a brand new non-login shell and doesn't inherit the current shell environment that it was run in.

Thank you again to everyone who tried to help, I would have given up if it wasn't for everyone's comments!